# R - PCA function

Tags: r

I am learning Principal component analysis in R. I found the below reference and found it quite good - https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/02/27/h2o . However, while walking through the code in the reference i am getting the below error :

```
Statement : pcaOutput <- pca(t(arrhythmia[-c(280, 281)]), printDropped = FALSE, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
Error     :Error in if (var(exprsData[i, ]) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone kindly help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help... I did follow the tutorial

I did not have `rsparkling` package so I did install it.

I see this during the installation:

```
Performing one-time download of h2o.jar from
     http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-vajda/3/Rjar/h2o.jar 
(This could take a few minutes, please be patient...)
```

Given that it install a `jar`, is your Java installation properly configured? I mean with solved PATH, `rJava` detecting your Java version, etc.

Also `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.0.0")` demands to install Spark so I run `spark_install(version = "2.0.0")` from R. While running `spark_connect` I see it connects to *java.org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit* as my firewall says, so I create the corresponding rules.

I followed the rest of the tutorial and I had to install `pcaGoPromoter`

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Bioconductor-mirror/pcaGoPromoter")
```

Finally... I'm able to reproduce

```
pcaOutput <- pca(t(arrhythmia[-c(280, 281)]), printDropped = FALSE, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
```

If you open the table in RStudio panel you'll see it has NA values, so I change the line for:

```
pcaOutput <- pca(na.omit(t(arrhythmia[-c(280, 281)])), printDropped = FALSE, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
```

and it works :)